# How to create modules/addons on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a web-app that will be used by several people.
All have the same basic app, but each one needs some extra features, which the others do not need.

I'm trying to create some how some modules or addons to the app, so each one can install them if need.

The basic behavior of each addon, would be add a `div` into the main page.

A link inside that `div` will redirect to an html inside the folder of the addon, so, there is no problem with that part,  I just need to add the div to the main page.

Which should be the correct way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your HTML + Controller + CSS built-in separately,
then all your 'consumers' have to do is include your javascript/css files, and use your template.

You can inject any template in AngularJS using `ngInclude`

```
<div ng-include="'addons/pablo.html'"></div>
```

Comment: and if the addon `pablo` is not present, it wont show anything nor throw any error?

Comment: If the html is not located it would throw a regular file not found exception.

Comment: But if there is a lot of available plugins, and the `customer` only install one, it will throw a lot of `file not found exception`

Comment: He references your code only once, thats the only point HE has to make sure exists. The rest of the errors from your own code, you can make sure doesn't throw any unnecessary errors.